# Activation lock on Ipad

Tags: ipad

My Ipad locked on it on I don't remember my I cloud ID or Password How do I unlock it? It came up on my Ipad Activation lock.

Answer (score -1):

Provided you can remember the answers you gave to your security questions, you can reset your password at https://appleid.apple.com.